# IIS Windows Authentication auto-logon with Internet Explorer

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, iis, windows-authentication

I have an ASP.NET application running on Windows Server 2012 R2, IIS 6.2.

Under IIS I set in the authentication Anonymous Authorization to Disabled and Windows Authentication to Enabled.

[image]

**On the client machine IE settings**:
Added the site's domain to trusted sites, set to medium-low security in this site and enabled automatic logon.

[image]

It still prompts client to login with a popup window. I thought it should just automatically send the client credentials. (Client machine and server (IIS) machine It is same domain as well).
Is it something missing? Am I doing something wrong? I am expecting it not to prompt for login, since user is already logged in to the domain. It should just send credentials of machine right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should add your site to the "Sites" in **"Local Intranet"** tab to get automatic logon, not **"Trusted"** one.

Comment: This seems to work. Thanks! Is it possible that these settings are fixing Chrome as well, because now that is working too?

Comment: AFAIK yes - Chrome (and all other browsers) use system-wide network settings from IE - go to Settings -> Advanced -> Network in Chrome and will get well-known IE tab :)